# Unity's IsPointerOverGameObject returning inconsistently

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm noticing that mouse clicks on my UI are also triggering Unity's `OnMouseDown` and similar events if there are world-space objects behind them.

Researching has led me to `EventSystems.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` which Unity docs don't explain very well.

According to the explanations, it should **return true** when the pointer is over a **ui object** but that's not my experience.

When using that, it returns `false` when over one Collider2D, `true` when over another, and `true` when over a UI object.

I don't understand what logic it's using to determine when to show true vs false. It's poorly named because *everything* is a "GameObject".

If I can figure out what's causing wrong info, I can fix it.

Otherwise, I need an alternative way to ignore world-space clicks when someone clicks anywhere in a UI element.

**Edit:** It appears that `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != null` is a more valuable indicator. That value has an actual UI object when a click occurs but doesn't for non-UI objects. It's only useful in `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseDrag` since it's value only exists on click though.

Comment: Thanks for this- been scratching my head for a whole day trying solutions that don't work. 

For me the issue is that for touch events  EventSystems.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() always returns false! So your fix of using EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != null was perfect.

:)